# Invalid Hooks error with react-redux that only shows up with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I have an app that uses typescript, react, and redux, and I'm trying to write a test case in Jest. Once I start using Redux's `useSelector`, I start getting "Invalid hook call" errors. **I've reviewed the Rules of Hooks, and I don't believe I'm breaking any of them**, but I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. Also, I only see the error when I run test cases in Jest; I never get an error when I build in the browser.

I've already confirmed that I'm using one version of React (18.2.0), a matching version of react-dom (18.2.0), and I have both redux (v4.2.1) and react-redux (v8.1.2). I only call hooks from within React components, and only at the top level.

So, here's all of the code... (I don't have a CodeSandbox account, but if it's necessary to create something like that, let me know)

When I run jest, here is my error:

> console.error
> Error: Uncaught [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
> See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.]
> at reportException (...\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
> at ...

These lines are also relevant:

> ```
>  19 | describe("Entry Point", () => {
>  20 |     it("should render successfully", () => {
>  21 |         const {baseElement} = render(<EntryPoint />);
>     |                                     ^
>  22 |         expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
>  23 |     });
>  24 | });
>
>  at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:63:23)
> ```

and

> Entry Point › should render successfully
>
> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
>
> ```
>  3 |
>  4 | const App = () => {
>  5 |   const name = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.ui.name);
>    |                           ^
>  6 |   return <div>{name}</div>;
>  7 | };
>  8 |
>
>  at resolveDispatcher (../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476:13)
>  at useRef (../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1515:20)
> ```

Here is the code I'm using:

App.tsx:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState } from "./store";

const App = () => {
  const name = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.logger.name);
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Note that `useSelector` is called from the top level of a React component.

App.test.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import App from "../src/App";
import { setupStore } from "../src/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

const EntryPoint = () => {
    const store = setupStore();

    return <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>;
};

describe("Entry Point", () => {
    it("should render successfully", () => {
        const {baseElement} = render(<EntryPoint />);
        expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

store.ts:

```
import { PreloadedState, combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducer from "./slice";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ui: reducer
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export const setupStore = (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) => {
    return configureStore({
        reducer: rootReducer,
        preloadedState
    });
};

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;
```

slice.ts:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type {PayloadAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface State {
    name: string;
}

const initialState: State = {
    name: "test",
};

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: "logger",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setName: (state, action: PayloadAction<State["name"]>) => {
            state.name = action.payload;
        },
    }
});

export const {
    setName
} = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

And, in case any of these configs are relevant, here's my package.json (incl jest config):

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --port 3457",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.5",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "8.1.2",
    "redux": "4.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "jsx",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.css$": "<rootDir>/tests/_styleMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a github repo where this issue exists?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not working in a public repo, so I can't share a link or anything

Comment: What if you remove the `<Provider />` component in `App.test.tsx`? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: `Error: Uncaught [Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>]`

Comment: Alirght. Use the provider, but pass `{}` to the `store` prop

Comment: That's not allowed in typescript. You get this ts error: `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Store<unknown, AnyAction>': dispatch, getState, subscribe, replaceReducer, [Symbol.observable]ts(2739)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255358/discussion-between-julianna-and-robin-thomas).